# Javascript: Change Global Var Locally

Tags: javascript, variables, global

Easy question. Just an explict look:

```
 var token = "12345"

function einloggen(){
    var test = particle.login({username: userName, password: passWord});
    test.then(
    function (data) {
            token = data.body.access_token;
            console.log('tokenoutprint1:', token);
            },
    function (err) {
            console.log('LoggingIn Failed', err);
            }
);
console.log('tokenoutprint2:', token);

}
einloggen();
```

after that i want to reuse the "new" token in a different Function...

```
callFunctionAVC(token);
```

The third last line will print me `12345`. But I want print out the "new" token, defined in. Like in "normal" java

I don't know why because the first console.log shows me the right token.

SO HOW DO I GET THE "TOKEN" TO A GLOBAL VARIABLE. Thats my "real" Question. Please send full codes only otherwise i won't get it.

Sorry for not being a pro, I'm just learning in school.

Greetings.

Comment: because you're using a promise its async therefore once the request is done it starts exicuting the non async function until its request is resolved or rejected it will have changed token just not when it console logs it

Comment: are you calling the function `einloggen` anywhere?

Comment: but i need it to be changed first cause i want to reuse that var in another function.

Comment: sure its just an explicit

Comment: @F3IIX8 call that other function from within promise then, just after you change token

Comment: whats promise?? im new... sry

Comment: @F3IIX8 call your  function after this code `token = data.body.access_token;
                        console.log('token', token);`  just where you call console.log, or after it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score -1):

The `einloggen` function is not (visibly) being called before the `console.log`, which means you set `token = "12345"`, `console.log()` it and some time later you may or may not call the `einloggen` function.

I think what you wanted to do is:

```
function einloggen() {
    //your code
}
einloggen(); // Execute the method
console.log(token);
```

There's a possibility this won't work as expected as well because you're using Promises in your `einloggen` function.

You could also try to execute `console.log(token)` from the developer console of your browser.

Comment: the problem is its an async call and hes logging it out before its been changed.

Comment: i know that i have to call that func. im not that dumb haha... but i don't know